# how to get location in android app without permission in manifest but with asking in app

Tags: android, permissions

I have an application to determine the type of available data network for users, in my last update I added a webservice to create a map of data network types of my users, app will get user's location, and send it to my server with just data network type (completely anonymous), but unfortunately the local market which I use to distribute my app thinks I should not ask for user's location permission (Coarse and fine) in manifest and somehow I need to remove these permissions from manifest and ask user's permission in my app  to do so.

Is it possible to do so ? using intent or whatever? how should I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to remove these permissions from manifest and ask user's permission in my app to do so. Is it possible to do so ?

Not in Android, at least through 4.4. You cannot request permissions from the user at runtime, only via the manifest.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to get user location without stating coarse and file location permissions in the manifest?

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi: There is no way to get the location from Android. Presumably, you are welcome to use the same "guess the city based on the IP address" stuff that Web apps use, though that tends to be very unreliable.